# Share memory access on SD card between a PC and an Android App

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, storage

When you connect an Android Phone with an SD Flash card to a PC, with the Disk Drive option selected, it temporarily will be impossible to access the flash from the an Android App. What about phones with internal Flash?

I am looking for a way to share memory between an android phone and a pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a wireless LAN and you just want to copy files around while the phone can still access the card then the simplest way is to install an FTP server on your phone like https://market.android.com/details?id=lutey.FTPServer

There are probably similar solutions using Bluetooth, 3G, etc.

Comment: I really need a usb solution.  My ultimate goal is to connect to a GPS USB host device, and pass info back to my android phone.

Answer (score 4):

There is apparently an app in the Market that does this.  I do not know the name.  It probably requires root.

However, **doing so is a *terrible* idea**.  Two operating systems should NEVER access the same disk at the same time, because they do not know about each other's writes.  If you do this you *will* lose data, possibly everything on your card.  There is no advantage to this anyways unless you are doing something extremely bizarre.

Comment: I am doing something fairly odd.  I have a GPS device that acts as a USB host.  I currently connect to is via a WM 6.5 phone.  I create a USB serial port, and pass data/commands back and forth.  I just bought a Android phone, and the SDK does not support USB serial.  I thought that I might be able to pass data back and forth via the mass storage feature.  I don't have the option of using Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.

Comment: You'd probable need the phone in Media mode and a custom application on both Android and your PC to synchronize with each other and transfer the info.